# casting integer field to a timestamp ... and then to a date

Tags: postgresql

**Background**

I need to write a SQL query that will sort records by date and then export the records to csv files, by month.

So for example, consider the following query and results:

```
select id, addy, abstime(start_ts) from wwdr where id > 3000;
```

output:

```
1361571 | :10011@mydomain| 2016-08-12 17:59:36+00
1361578 | :19448@mydomain| 2016-08-12 17:59:16+00
1361579 | :10307@mydomain| 2016-08-12 18:00:07+00
1361581 | :10702@mydomain| 2016-08-12 17:54:41+00
1361582 | :12264@mydomain| 2016-08-12 18:00:13+00
1361588 | :10561@mydomain| 2016-09-12 18:00:20+00
1361589 | :10126@mydomain| 2016-09-12 18:00:13+00
1361593 | :25743@mydomain| 2016-09-12 17:54:03+00
1361597 | :13150@mydomain| 2016-03-12 17:58:10+00
1361600 | :14513@mydomain| 2016-03-12 18:00:36+00
1361602 | :46003@mydomain| 2016-03-12 18:00:31+00
1361603 | :11534@mydomain| 2016-03-12 18:01:11+00
1361608 | :58064@mydomain| 2016-01-12 18:00:45+00
1361614 | :14516@mydomain| 2016-02-12 18:00:16+00
1361620 | :14505@mydomain| 2016-08-12 17:57:13+00
1361621 | :13844@mydomain| 2016-08-12 17:50:44+00
1361623 | :333@mydomain  | 2016-08-12 18:02:29+00
1361625 | :58066@mydomain| 2016-08-12 18:02:23+00
1361532 | :222@mydomain  | 2016-08-12 17:58:24+00
1361541 | :30172@mydomain| 2016-08-12 17:57:56+00
1361542 | :10011@mydomain| 2018-02-12 17:56:37+00
1361545 | :333@mydomain  | 2018-02-12 17:58:55+00
```

How can I need to write a query that will create a separate CSV file for each month? For instance, it should end up with:

- 2016-08-12.csv
- 2016-09-12.csv
- 2016-03-12.csv

for the example above.

And the other twist is for the stuff that's current, I need it to be in a file called `current.csv`.

It doesn't have to all be in PLSQL.  I'm writing a bash script to wrap this logic up. But I just need some ideas on where to start with the queries.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**

Before adding to a script, i'm trying to run things on the command line to understand what exactly the proposed answer is doing.
So this is the command i run:

```
lab-1:/etc/# for x in $(psql -U testuser testdb -h db-lab-2.mydomain.net -t -A -c "SELECT *, CASE WHEN DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', ABSTIME(start_ts)) = DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', CURRENT_DATE) THEN 'current' ELSE DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', ABSTIME(start_ts))::DATE::TEXT END FROM widgets limit 10");
do
> echo "---$x --- is the result"
> done
```

And this is the output that I see: (just a snippet)

```
---3879602|2017-06-14 --- is the result
---14:25:40.862729|Completed|local|in|0|10571|10563|1497464696|1497464740|44|846ef34f-df2ef574-8834f0af|22|123||2017-06-01 --- is the result
---3879604|2017-06-14 --- is the result
---14:25:49.770659|Completed|local|in|0|3093685567|10096|1497464737|1497464749|12|a560b92b-cbd1-1235-5fb3-003018a67b79|asd|fasdf||2017-06-01 --- is the result
```

The first line you see contains two fields, the id 3879602 and part of another field called im_date which is defined as "timestamp without time zone | default now()"
But as you can see the line gets cut off right when the time portion starts. 
Can you explain why this is happening?

Comment: Be careful with time zones when you start chopping up your data. Defining a month as "12 AM on the first of the month, thru 11:59:59 PM on the last day of the month" means a different set of seconds when dealing with your local time zone vs. UTC.

Comment: ok.  thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the file name by casting the time value to date, and if you mean *current month* with *stuff that's current*, you can use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN 
        DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', ABSTIME(start_ts)) = DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', CURRENT_DATE) 
    THEN 'current' 
    ELSE 
        DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', ABSTIME(start_ts))::DATE::TEXT 
    END, 
    id, addy, ABSTIME(start_ts) 
FROM wwdr WHERE id > 3000;
```

You can fetch the raw data in `bash` and parse them with `sed`:

```
for l in $(psql -t -A -c "SELECT ...")
do
    filename=$(echo $l | sed 's/^\([^|]*\)\|.*$/\1/')
    echo $l | sed 's/^[^|]*\|//' >> "${filename}.csv"
done
```

**Addendum**: Your statement should ensure that the date for the file names is the first column like:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN 
        DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', ABSTIME(start_ts)) = DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', CURRENT_DATE) 
    THEN 'current' 
    ELSE 
        DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', ABSTIME(start_ts))::DATE::TEXT 
    END, * 
FROM widgets LIMIT 10
```

To get more control over the file names you may use `TO_CHAR`:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN 
        DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', ABSTIME(start_ts)) = DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', CURRENT_DATE) 
    THEN 'current'
    ELSE
        TO_CHAR(ABSTIME(start_ts), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    END, * 
FROM widgets limit 10
```

Comment: clemens, can you just help me figure out / fix the file names?  it seems to be creating some csvs but the names look like this: 14:51:02+00.csv

Comment: @dot: Sorry, a necessary cast was missing.

Comment: no worries. the other thing i'm noticing is that the bash loop - it's returning more rows because it truncates after the space in the start_ts.  will update my question with some sample output

Comment: clemens i added the ::DATE::TEXT but it's still creating funky file names with time stamp portion instead of y/m/d portion.

Comment: @dot: Ha, I see. You should ensure that the _first column_ of the output is the date. Move the asterix behind the `CASE` expression.